# How to use libigl library on Matlab

Tags: matlab, windows-10, libigl

I'm trying to use libigl library for a program in Matlab R2016 on windows 10 but i can't understand how to set it and I haven't found a tutorial. Maybe is something trivial but I need help. Have you some hint/tutorial that can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: I encapsulate many libigl functions for matlab in my gptoolbox library ( https://github.com/alecjacobson/gptoolbox/tree/master/mex ). libigl has some helper routines to make this easer ( in https://github.com/libigl/libigl/tree/master/include/igl/matlab , specifically parse_rhs and prepare_lhs to go between matlab and eigen types).